# Shutdown, suspend require authentication when scheduled in at

Tags: systemd, at, polkit, logind

I'd like to suspend my laptop using [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at):

```
echo "systemctl suspend" | at now + 5 minutes
```

Suspension does not happen, instead I find a mail from `at` in `/var/spool/mail/me`:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to suspend system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to start suspend.target: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status suspend.target' for details.
```

Alright, `logind` requires authentication when `at` runs `systemctl suspend`. This is interesting since when I run `systemctl suspend` directly, without `at`, no authentication is required and the machine goes into suspension.

I've made sure that the commands executed with `at` are run by the same non-root user as the commands run directly using `echo "echo $(who) > who.txt" | at now`.

Suspecting that authentication is required in `at` because it runs the commands via `/bin/sh` (which is an alias for bash), I executed `systemctl suspend` after starting `/bin/sh`: Suspending happens immediately without authentication, indicating that the nested shell is not the reason why suspending fails when done with `at`.

I get the same behavior and very similar mails when doing `echo "reboot" | at now` and `echo "shutdown now" | at now`.

My question is: How does `logind` figure out that it's `at` that tries to suspend, reboot, or shut down the machine and how can I tell `logind` that it should allow `at` to execute those commands without authentication?

---

I'm on Arch Linux 4.18.1 with `at` version 3.1.19.

Comment: Can you run `echo 'echo $(who) > who.txt' | at now`? I think $(who) will be evaluated by the shell otherwise.

Comment: Hi Stefan! `echo 'echo $(who) > who.txt' | at now` writes `me tty1 2018-08-26 13:13` to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the commands run by `at` are in a different environment, without access to your tty device and dbus settings and so on.

Systemd has its own version of the `at` command. You can use it to run your command in an environment that seems to be ok for further systemd commands.
So use the equivalent command:

```
systemd-run --user --on-active=5min /bin/systemctl suspend
```

For perfect accuracy in the wait time of 5 minutes, you need to add option `--timer-property=AccuracySec=1`.

Comment: Thanks @meuh, `systemd-run` works great. @jasonwryan added the `polkit` tag to the question; do you think that's part of the environment that's different in `at`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about polkit. It's all very compilcated. The `at` command is very old, so might sit outside all this new stuff. It is probably the same as for `cron`. You'll see many questions on having trouble making commands work from cron. If there are any solutions they probably apply to `at` too. `man systemd-logind.service` mentions policykit and provides some links to explore.