# Using 'at' and 'systemctl' commands together

Tags: systemd, sudo, shutdown, at

I'm trying to schedule shutdown of PC using at command like this:

```
echo "systemctl poweroff" | at -M now +1 minute
```

or like this:

```
echo "sudo systemctl poweroff" | at -M now +1 minute
```

but nothing happens. Why?

`atd` is running and the command below works fine just to check it out:

```
echo "echo Hello 2>&1 > /home/<user_name>/at-test.txt" | at -M now +1 minute
```

I know that shutdown can be scheduled using `shutdown -P TIME` but please answer my question first instead of pointing out some alternatives.
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `systemctl` or `sudo` doesn't try to ask for your password when the time comes? If it does then this won't work because there is no tty available to it, I think.

Comment: Even in cases where `sudo` doesn't require a password (tag `NOPASSWD`), it might still check that there's a, roughly speaking, interactive session (i.e. option `requiretty`). Defaults on that seem to vary between distros, though, but `sudo -l` should list the explicitly set options that apply to you.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes I'm sure, I checked this out several times. As I had already mentioned - nothing happens, literally nothing.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz,
I'm using Ubuntu though I'm not fond of it. And my user has (ALL : ALL) ALL - default 'sudo' privileges as for Ubuntu distro.

Answer (score 1):

Policy Kit can apply rules to `shutdown` and `poweroff` (which are just the `systemctl` program by another name) run in non-login-session context as an `at` job that are different to the rules applied to `shutdown` run in login-session context.

`sudo` just over-eggs this pudding, adding unnecessary extra complication.  systemd is *already* applying rules as to which unprivileged users, in which contexts, can successfully trigger a system shutdown.  Adding `sudo` with its additional mechanisms *on top of all that* just doubles the number of access rulesets and increases the number of possible cases that one has to consider when diagnosing problems.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465337/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/5132
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2014).  [`systemd-logind.service`](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html). systemd manual pages.  freedesktop.org.
- [Shutdown, suspend require authentication when scheduled in at](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464905/)
- [Disable "shutdown" and "poweroff" command in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263884/)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/536591/